# checkmarx: Stored Absolute Path Traversal for Files.readAllBytes and Files.readAllLines

Tags: security, checkmarx, sast

I catch "Stored Absolute Path Traversal" for 2 operations in my Java code:

```
 byte[] buffer = Files.readAllBytes(dir);
                 Files.readAllLines(dir)
```

Argument dir is created as follows:

```
 Path dir = Paths.get(Paths.get(base, parts).normalize().toString().replace(" ", "_"));
```

So, I tried to sanitize path creation, by normalization and replace of empty characters, but this does not work.

Also I tried to apply File(path).getCanonicalPath():

```
 String canonicalPath;
 String path = Paths.get(base, parts)
    .normalize()
    .toString().replace(" ", "_");
try {
    canonicalPath = new File(path).getCanonicalPath();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeExceptione);
 }
```

But with the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the File.getCanonicalPath method to resolve any symbolic links, relative paths, or redundant components in the parts parameter.
2. Use the File.getAbsolutePath method to get the absolute path of the base parameter.

Comment: I updated my question with attempt of applying File.getCanonicalPath.  This does not work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function to sanitize the path

```
private static String sanitizePathTraversal(String filename) {
 Path p = Paths.get(filename);
 return p.getFileName().toString();
}
```

It worked in my case.

Add this function and modify your code like this:

```
canonicalPath = new File(sanitizePathTraversal(path));
```